# What is the equivalent selenium code for the chrome?(Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I  have written a simple selenium code that downloads files into the custom directory. The code is
for firefox:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
# 0 for desktop
# 1 for default download folder
# 2 for specific folder
# You can specify directory by using profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir","<>")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",dest_dir1)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);

# If you don't have some download manager then you can remove these
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);

driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
```

Now, I want to create a similar type of script for chrome. I just want the chrome script to download into the `dest_dir1`. I don't see any options like `webdriver.ChromeProfile` similar to `webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`.

Comment: This stuff is all over the internet already. Where have you looked? What have you tried? What weren't you able to get working?

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory": "YOUR DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY",
         "download.directory_upgrade": True,
         "download.manager.showWhenStarting": False,
         "download.manager.useWindow": False,
         "helperApps.alwaysAsk.force":False,
         "download.manager.showAlertOnComplete": False}

}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, path="EXECUTABLE CHROME DRIVER PATH")
```

I have added few tags hope you understand how it works and build your own preference option.